# Chained ajax request with jquery promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following code. What I am doing is that first I make an ajax request to first url. I get a response and I need some data from that response. For that reason, I put that data into `user` object. That response also include another url. Then I make another ajax request to that new url. And I get response from the url and I add that data to `user` object. In the last `then()` function I return `user` object. However, when I call `get().done(function(data) { console.log(data) })`, I only get `user.data` array only. It does not include user's detail in first ajax request. **How can I merge the data from these two requests and return as a promise(deferred maybe)?**

```
    var get = function() {
        var user = {};

        return $.ajax({
            url: 'URL',
            method: 'GET',
            type: 'JSON'
        }).then(function(user) {
            user['name'] = user.name;
            user['joined'] = user.create_at;

            return $.ajax({
                url: user.url,
                method: 'GET',
                type: 'JSON'
            });
        }).then(function(data) {
            user['data'] = data;
            return user;
        });
    },
```

Comment: `var user = {};` that `user` isn't the same as the `user` in `function(user) {` and what you are doing in the first 2 lines of that callback is essentially nothing ... rename `var user` to `var anythingButUserOrDataForThatMatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function

```
function(user) {
    user['name'] = user.name;
    user['joined'] = user.create_at;

    return $.ajax({
        url: user.url,
        method: 'GET',
        type: 'JSON'
    });
}
```

You are creating a `user` variable in the function's local [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). So when you do `user['name'] = user.name;`, on the left part of the assignment, you are not referring to the `var user = {}` you defined outside, at the highest scope, but to the local `user`.

Try naming the fetched `user` data something else, like `userData`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `context` option of `$.ajax()` calls to `user` object

```
var get = function() {
    var user = {};

    return $.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        method: 'GET',
        type: 'JSON',
        context: user
    }).then(function(user) {
        this['name'] = user.name;
        this['joined'] = user.create_at;

        return $.ajax({
            url: user.url,
            method: 'GET',
            type: 'JSON',
            context: this
        });
    }).then(function(data) {
        this['data'] = data;
        return this;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your second .then inside the first .then (chained onto the $.ajax call) like so

```
var get = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        method: 'GET',
        type: 'JSON'
    }).then(function(user) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: user.url,
            method: 'GET',
            type: 'JSON'
        }).then(function(data) {
            return {
                name: user.name,
                joined: user.create_at,
                data: data
            };
        });
    });
},
```

no need for any other variables at all

Comment: I think the only drawback is that if multiple AJAX calls are required, you are going to perform a lot of unnecessary nesting?

Comment: as there are only two in this case I didn't even consider nesting an issue, but yes, the pyramid of doom beckons using this method